# Yosemite Messages: Support for a separate speaker for notifications?

Tags: macos, messages, skype, jabber

I'm using a jabber account with Messages for voice and video calling, as well as chat. I also use a headset most of the time, and have it set as my primary audio device, but want to hear if someone tries to call or send me a message.

Does Messages support the ability to set different speakers for conversations and notifications a la Skype?

I have poked around in the preferences and done a bit of Googling, with no luck.

Comment: There is no way to do this, as far as I am aware.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like this is not possible after all.